# Can't connect ButtonBarItem IBAction to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to connect an `IBAction` from a `TabBarController` to several buttons that are inside ViewControllers which are each in a `NavigationController` whose are part of the `TabBarController`.

In the TabBarController I have the IBAction...

```
@IBAction func onSettingsCloseButtonTap(sender:AnyObject)
{
}
```

This is a part from the storyboard:

[image]

Left top is the `TabBarController`, middle are the Nav Controllers and on the right the views that have the buttons.

But I can't connect the IBAction to the buttons (or even one button). What do I need to do to wire it in a way to have the buttons invoke the IBAction in the `TabBarController`?

Additionally, is it even possible to assign several buttons to the same IBAction or would I need a method for each of them?

Comment: why don't you keep the IBActions in the view controller's themselves? if you need the tab bar controller to do something, you can send a notification or use delegates..

Comment: You can connect an action of a Button to its view controller **only**. If you want to send action (or notify) about the button's action, you would need to build your own broadcasting mechanism. (Delegates or NSNotifications)

Comment: What would you expect a Done button to do when placed within a ViewController that's displayed via UITabBar?

Comment: @Acey yeah it's a bit suboptimal in this case. The tab bar control is in a popover view and the button(s) should close the popover view. Because the TabBarController doesn't have a top nav bar where I could place a single button, I wrapped the sub views in Nav controllers and each of them has a close button.

Comment: @GoodSp333d Ok thanks for the info! I think I have to overthink my architecture for this part.